# My email signature needs to be edge to edge instead of being to the left

Tags: html

I have created a small html signature but its inline, to the left and my boss needs it to be edge to edge instead of being inclined to the left. I need to fix this but i'm not very good at html so i'd love some advice, or better still somebody who can help me redo it, well i know its a walk in the park for anybody good at Html :-)

Here is the code.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" colspan="2">
          <span style="text-align: left; color: #52524D; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13pt; font-weight: bold"><b>Mathenge Anthony</b> |<i><small> Intern</small></i></span>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 0px;" colspan="2">
          <a href="http://www.systechafrica.com"><img src="http://www.qualitexsolutions.com/img/works/systech.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="200" height="120" alt='Systech Africa' title='Systech Africa' /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" colspan="2"><span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"> 1st Floor Mayfair Business Centre, Parklands Road, Westlands &nbsp;<font size="1" color="#B9B9B9"><br></font>&nbsp;P.O. Box 41964 - 00100&nbsp;<font size="1" color="#B9B9B9">|</font>&nbsp;Nairobi, Kenya.<br></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 7pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"><font color="#828282"><b>Phone:</b></font>&nbsp; </span></td>
        <td align="left" width="100%" valign="top" style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"> (+254) 020 2115993/3742207 </span></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 7pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"><font color="#828282"><b>Mobile:</b></font>&nbsp; </span></td>
        <td align="left" width="100%" valign="top" style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"> 0723-847842, 0786-384784 </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 7pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"><font color="#828282"><b>Fax:</b></font>&nbsp; </span></td>
        <td align="left" width="100%" valign="top" style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;"><span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"> (+254) 020 224 0363 </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" colspan="2"><span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; color: #00ADEF; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: #00ADEF" href="http://www.systechafrica.com/"><font color="#00ADEF">website</font></a>&nbsp;<font size="1" color="#00ADEF">&nbsp;<font size="1" color="#00ADEF">|</font>&nbsp;<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #00ADEF" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Systech+Limited/@-1.262282,36.808949,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xf5bbb42d28fa1a88"><font color="#00ADEF">map</font></a>&nbsp;<font size="1" color="#00ADEF">|</font>&nbsp;<a style="text-decoration: none; color: #00ADEF" href="mailto:info@systechafrica.com"><font color="#00ADEF">email</font></a></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" colspan="2">
          <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/y4lzmrxut/Fundmaster.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="250" height="70" alt="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" width="100%" colspan="2">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/SystechLtdKE"><img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="22" height="20" alt="Twitter" /></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SystechLimited">
            <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="22" height="20" alt="Facebook" /></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/systech-limited"><img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/linkedin.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="22" height="20" alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
          <a href="https://plus.google.com/115976292984421142673/about"><img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/google.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="22" height="20" alt="google+" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<style>
  a {color: #00ADEF;}
</style>

</html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly: `<style>` and `<meta>` tags should be inside `<head>` tag.

Secondly: Let this be your starting point ;)

```
<table style="border:1px solid black; width:600px">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left">I'm on left</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">I'm on right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tip: You can place another table inside `<td>`

Comment: Error. In emails, `<style>` and all of content you need to show needs to put inside `<body>` tag, because some email clients (like gmail) removes all `<head>` contents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this method works and i am able to align to the left, centre and right. But now if i specify two elements to the left,they seem to leave a space between them but are aligned on the same line.I would like one to go below the other.Eg,the logo to go below the name, instead of being inline (i know i sound stupid lol). Thank you

Comment: Please, show us a jsfiddle.com . Just fill your code in there, press SAVE and share link with us.

Comment: Great here you go https://jsfiddle.net/zevku1pp/  I would like the Logo to go below my name, if its possible. Thank you

Comment: Simplest solution is to pack in `<div>` everything you need to be in separate lines (eg. `<div><b>I'm on first line</b></div><div>i'm on second</div>`) or just to use `<br>` tag. Remember that images are _inline_ objects so if you want them to work like `div` then add them `display:block` style.

Answer (score 0):

Add width to your table

```
 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

Is magic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I have tried but its not working, i think you misunderstood my query. The whole email signature is on the left.What do i do to sort of "cut" it and have a piece of it align and be full width instead of one long, horizontal thing.

Comment: You can try the secondly thing that @Volvox said in the other answer :)

Comment: Thank you, it works but i still need just, a little more help!